# Change time zone IIS10 log

Tags: iis-10

I want to change time zone for my IIS10 logs (now timestamp is UTC-2 hours).
This guide is ok for previous IIS version:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/271196/iis-log-file-entries-have-the-incorrect-date-and-time-stamp

Utility convlog is not present on the server (it's a Windows Server 2016)

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Did you check https://labs.rebex.net/RConvLog?